# How to add a .png image as a background to a link with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, css, image, codeigniter

I can't solve the problem.

I'm working on a `PHP` project with `CodeIgniter`, in the **DisplayData** `views` I have a table with data and in 2 columns I have **links** that when clicked call a function.

What I'm trying to do is use an **image** instead of **links**, ie set it as a link background.

I downloaded the image and inserted it in the folder where the views are `(application/views/delete.png)`.

I tried to modify the **CSS** `background-image: URL("basket.png");` but it doesn't work, I also tried to add the tag image

```
<a class=\"elimin\" href='deletedata?id=".$row-> id. "id> tag
<img src = "<? php echo base_url ('basket.png');?>
</a>
```

but he doesn't work either.

I also tried to write `<img src = 'application/views/basket.png' />` but this doesn't work either

Can anyone tell me how can I do please?

**DisplayData Views**

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> ".$row->id."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row->testo."</td>";
      echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"myVariable\" value=\"'.$row->stato.'\"/><br/>";

      echo "<td>  Da fare </td>";


      echo "<td> 

<a class=\"modifica\" href='updatedata?id=".$row->id."'>Modifica</a>

</td>";

 //<input type='submit' name='update' value='Cancella'>

echo "<td><a class=\"elimina\" href='deletedata?id=".$row->id."'>
Elimina</a></td>";


  echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a good folder structure. All the Images/JS/CSS/etc.. should be placed outside the `application` folder.

```
application <== where the code placed
assets  <== where all the Images/JS/CSS placed
   - images
   - css
   - js
system <== system file
index.php <== inedx file
```

Then below code will work

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/basket.png"/>
```

---

**FYI**

In view no need to use `echo` all the time. you can just remove `<?php` from top of the file and just use HTML's. If you need anything with PHP just wrap those only with `<?= ?>`(PHP short tag must be enabled) or `<?php echo ?>`

Comment: I'm sorry but the code doesn't work, I created a new folder called Assets outside the Application folder, then I created an Images folder inside it and placed the image inside it, but the `echo code "<td> <a class = "delete href = 'deletedata? id =". $ row-> id. "'>
<img src = "<? php echo base_url ()?> assets / images / basket.png" />
Delete </a> </td> ";` it doesn't work

Comment: did you add the image to image folder

Comment: i have add this `<img src = '../../assets/images/update.png' />` into <a> tag and it works